# Setting state in a callback of another setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Would it be problematic to set other state while in a callback to set state? For example code below:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const onChange = useCallback(
    (name, value) =>
      setValues((values) => {
        const newValues = { ...values, [name]: value };
        setErrors(validate(newValues));//set other state while in a callback
        return newValues;
      }),
    []
  );
  return '';
};
```

Or would it be better to combine values and errors:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    values: {},
    errors: {},
  });
  const onChange = useCallback(
    (name, value) =>
      setForm((form) => {
        const values = { ...form.values, [name]: value };
        const errors = validate(values);
        return { values, errors };
      }),
    []
  );
  const { errors, values } = form;
  return '';
};
```

Comment: I would use the single `setState`. It actually reads better, and in theory will perform better.

Comment: Keeping errors and values separate is better, but don't you think you should be validating the values first and then setting the state instead of setting the values state and then validating?

Comment: @rzwnahmd `but don't you think you should be validating the values first and then setting the state instead of setting the values state and then validating?` What if the value has to be minimum 8 characters? The user will never be able to type them.